# Screen not turning off on Lenovo Carbon Yoga X1 (running NixOS/Linux) when closing lid

Tags: linux, laptop, display, nixos

I've got a Lenovo Carbon Yoga X1 (1st gen). Running NixOS/Linux.

When closing the lid of the laptop, the LCD does not actually turn off, nor does seem to go into any sort of suspend mode.

How can I diagnose this issue? Which software / utilities are usually involved in this functionality?

Comment: See if there is a keyboard command or mouse selection to suspend. Most operating systems have such facility. What happens when you suspend with the screen open.

Comment: Ha yeah that doesn't seem to work either - I mean pressing the power button does nothing. Though `systemctl suspend` works.

Comment: See if you can find Power Drivers for your system. Perhaps ask Lenovo Support.

Comment: For my System76 w/ NixOS I simply suspend by command (tell the OS to sleep/suspend) and close the lid. I suspect would need to trigger this or at least turn of the screen by getting a signal somehow from the laptop firmware. I don't know how to do that tho.